# Java TextIO.putf() method

Tags: java, printf

I have a problem with the method TextIO.putf method (which should have the same result as System.out.printf).

This is the code that is giving me problems:

```
for (int columns = 0; columns < 3; columns++) {   
    for (int rows = 0; rows < 4; rows++) {   
        TextIO.putf("%5d", "-");   
    } 
    TextIO.putln(); 
}
```

When I run the application, it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal format string in TextIO.putf() method.

This is dictated from the "-" part, since if I put something else there (I tried with the number 4, for example) it prints correctly this:

```
4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4
```

How can I fix this? Why is this giving me errors with the "-" instead of any number? I tried to look up for this both in the TextIO source code and on the internet, and I still don't know why (since the second variable of the putf method should be Object type).

Thanks to everyone that will help me out!

Answer (score 1):

The d in %5d signals, that you want to print a decimal number.

The 5 in that expression says, that the number should have the length of 5 digits, if the number is shorter, it pads the number with blanks.

If you want to print a string, use %s instead of %5d.